# Why second string save in first string?

Tags: c++

I have a c++ application that will start my c# application and in one method I have below strings

```
const BSTR S1 = _bstr_t("String1");
const BSTR S2 = _bstr_t("String2");
```

I have break point when compiler execute line1 **S1 is String1** but when it will execute line2 **S1 will be String2**

I want to know why this happens?

Comment: @NathanOliver missread the topic completely, removed it.

Comment: Kindly show us a complete example; also, use some kind of output (like std::cout) to verify variables. Debuggers sometimes go wild because of optimization, std::cout is / should be standard conforming.

Comment: In fact in these two variables are the name of class and method in my assembly(c#) and using that to create instance of class and run method.I have tested this application last year with vs 2012 but now I use vs 2015 I have got this problem . I downloaded from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674455/Anti-Reflector-NET-Code-Protection

Comment: @lorro if it was for debugger so my program must run correctly.becuase string1 is method name and string2 is class name it will load assembly but because name of class is stored in method name it can't start.last year I tested it it worked .but now don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_bstr_t1` is a wrapper class for a `BSTR`. The constructor allocates a `BSTR` (or increments a reference count if a copy) and the destructor frees the `BSTR` when the reference counter hits zero.

So

```
const BSTR S1 = _bstr_t("String1");
```

Does 3 things:

1. Creates a temporary, unnamed `_bstr_t` containing a `BSTR` that points to "String1" allocated somewhere in memory.
2. assigns the `BSTR` to `S1`. This is a copy of a pointer. No data is allocated or moved.
3. destroys the temporary `_bstr_t` because it is never assigned to anything and therefore has effectively one operation's worth of scope.

The `_bstr_t` reference count hits zero so the `BSTR` is freed. This means the memory `S1` points at has been freed and can be reused for the second line. Using `S1` will result in undefined behaviour, so as much as looking at it in the debugger could summon C'thulu from the nether realms to consume all of our souls. Fortunately the program crashing is much more likely.

Solution:

Either keep the `_bstr_t`s around

```
_bstr_t S1("String1");
// use S1
```

or do it the hard way

```
const BSTR S1 = SysAllocString(L"String1");
// use S1
SysFreeString(S1);
```

The first option should be the safer.

[`_bstr_t` documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx)

Comment: Why not `_bstr_t S1("String1");`? Is there some reason to do `_bstr_t S1 = _bstr_t("String1");` instead?

Comment: That would be my brain on drugs. Probably compile to the same thing, but... Fixing. Thanks.